# Override Mantine styles to only one element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, antd, mantine

In my React project, I am using **Mantine's** library **accordion in** two different components: **Search.jsx and Profile.jsx**.

The point is **I need to accurately customize its styles only in Profile** so I inspected the element and discovered that the default Mantine's class is named *mantine-bgzycs*. I applied styles to that class in Profile.css and it worked as I wanted.

The problem is **that affects to Search's accordion element too**.

When I inspect I can see also a Mantine's default ID but it changes dinamically.
I tried to envolve the elemen with a div and apply styles but most of them are overwritten by Mantine.

**QUESTIONS:**

Is there a way to apply styles only to one element of the same class?

Is there a way to restrict styles between React components?

Is there a way to access to Mantine's source and edit accurately an element styles?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one way to achieve what you're after. My preferred approach is documented in the [Styles API panel](https://mantine.dev/core/accordion/?t=styles) of the Accordion documentation and in the theming documentation under [create styles](https://mantine.dev/theming/create-styles/) and [Styles API](https://mantine.dev/theming/styles-api/)

Here is an example:

```
import { createStyles, Accordion } from '@mantine/core';

// define custom classes - includes access to theme object
const useStyles = createStyles((theme) => ({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
}));


function Demo() {
  const { classes } = useStyles();

  return (
    <Accordion
// apply custom classes to target Styles API properties
      classNames={{ item: classes.item }}>
      <Accordion.Item label="Customization">
        Blah, blah, blah
      </Accordion.Item>

    </Accordion>
  );
}
```

Comment: Excellent. That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can override object in a variable. Use `MantineThemeOverride` type - see [docs](https://mantine.dev/theming/theme-object/).

For example override `Text` component:

```
const componentsOveride:MantineThemeOverride["components"] = {
  Text: {
    styles: (theme, params, { variant }) => ({
      root:{
        fontSize: variant ==="heading" ? "32px":"16px"
      }
    }),
  },
  }


  export const theme:MantineThemeOverride = {
    components: componentsOveride,
    fontFamily: "var(--font-inter)",
    colorScheme: "light",
    primaryColor: "primary",
    primaryShade: 5,
  }
```

App with `MantineProvider`:

```
export default function App({children}:{children: React.ReactNode}){

  return(<MantineProvider theme={theme}>{children}<?MantineProvider>)
}
```